# Filtering seasonal time series outliers

Tags: r, filtering, time-series, outliers

I have some weather-related data that is highly seasonal, what i want to do is
to identify some 'outliers' and change these outliers to reasonable values (i dont wan't to remove them).

I'm using the **hampel** filter from the **pracma** package to identify and correct these outliers, but the problem is that some seasonal-peaks are being lowered too much. I guess
this function doesn't take into account seasonality. 
The plot below shows this (window of 24 months), the red line is the filtered data.

Is there a way to correct this?In other words, take the 'peaks' and average them between seasons?
Thanks!
[image]

Comment: I doubt that such tinkering with data is a good idea. I find the "note" in `?hampel` quite instructive.

Comment: Can they really be called outliers when each year has a ~50% chance of one occuring?

Comment: Yes - these high values are El Nino related, if i neglect them, my model gives too high forecasts (that never happened since 1931/jan).

Comment: If you really believe there are outliers in your dataset, you would need to first remove the seasonal trend, remove outliers from the detrended data, then retrend your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @Michael, here's some code that remove the seasonal component, apply a outlier filter on the remaining serie, and adds the seasonal component again (use by your own risk):

```
filter.outliers = function(serie.orig)
{
require(forecast)
require(pracma)

## get a stl decomposition object
stl.decomp = stl(serie.orig, s.window = 'periodic', t.window = 13, robust = T)

## remove the seasonal component
serie.desaz = seasadj(stl.decomp)

## apply a hampel filter
serie.desaz2 = hampel(serie.desaz, k = 12)$y

## put back the seasonal component
return(serie.desaz2 + stl.decomp$time.series[, 'seasonal'])
}
```

[image]